# If control in linq query entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

,Hi

```
List<Claimant> list = (from c in CacheManager.ClaimantList.List
where 

     c.Fullname.Replace("i", "İ").Replace("ı","I").ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.Replace("i", "İ").Replace("ı", "I").ToUpper())
  || c.IdentityNumber.Replace("i", "İ").Replace("ı", "I").ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.Replace("i", "İ").Replace("ı", "I").ToUpper())
  || c.TaxNumber.Replace("i", "İ").Replace("ı", "I").ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.Replace("i", "İ").Replace("ı", "I").ToUpper())

 select c).Take(20).ToList<Claimant>();
```

If Taxnumber is null or "" i get exception because of null data.

**My question:**

How can i set Taxnumber == 0 , **if Taxnumber is null or ""** ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe regex it is a good option

Comment: may you please share code example according to above code block i will accept best answer if solves

Comment: You should probably break that query into more querries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want certain columns and you don't need the whole `Claimant` object, you can put something into a `select`

```
from c in ClaimantList
where (...)
select new {c.FullName, c.IdentityNumber, TaxNumber = String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TaxNumber) ? "0" : c.TaxNumber}
```

You now have an anonymous type with three fields: original `FullName`, original `IdentityNumber` and modified `TaxNumber`.

---

You could also create a new `Claimant` for each value by calling its constructor each time:

```
from c in ClaimantList
where (...)
select new Claimant() {FullName = c.FullName, IdentityNumber = c.IdentityNumber, TaxNumber = String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TaxNumber) ? "0" : c.TaxNumber}
```

(I don't know what the constructor of `Claimant` is like, you might do this slightly differently and set those values in the constructor rather than in the initializer. Or you could write a new constructor.) If the constructor does something non-trivial, it might be wasteful of resources to call it this many times.

In either case, it is stylistically nice to put the conversion (`String.IsNullOrEmpty(TaxNumber) ? "0" : TaxNumber` or whatever) into its own function somewhere, so that you can change what conversion you do later (see below), and don't have to repeat the code in multiple places.

---

Another option is that you could use the objects you have, but change the `TaxNumber` as required. LINQ isn't really the best way of doing this, as you are basically applying side-effects. (LINQ likes to supply a new container with the right data in it, rather than change the data in the original container.) You should really run `foreach` outside of the Linq code, like this:

```
List<Claimant> list = from ...
                      where ...
                      select ...

foreach (Claimant claimant in list)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(claimant.TaxNumber))
    { claimant.TaxNumber = "0"; }
}
```

Ideally you do this after the `Take(20)` so that you only do it the number of times you need.

---

Again, putting the conversion in a function will be neater and nicer:

```
List<Claimant> list = from ...
                      where ...
                      select ...

foreach (Claimant claimant in list)
{
    claimant.TaxNumber = NormalizeTaxNumber(claimant.TaxNumber); }
}

// ...

public static string NormalizeTaxNumber(string n)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(n) ? "0" : n;
}
```

---

However, if you have gone down this route, the next option is to add a method to `Claimant` which does this change:

```
List<Claimant> list = from ...
                      where ...
                      select ...

foreach (Claimant claimant in list)
{
    claimant.NormalizeTaxNumber();
}

public class Claimant
{
    // ...

    public void NormalizeTaxNumber()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TaxNumber))
        { TaxNumber = "0"; }
    }
}
```

and to call this from the foreach loop.

---

Or, use a different property than `TaxNumber`:

```
public class Claimant
{
    // ...

    public string NormalTaxNumber
    {
        get { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(TaxNumber) ? "0" : TaxNumber; }
    }
}
```

The advantage of the first strategy is that you only have to call it once - the advantages of the second are that it keeps the original value still available (in the `TaxNumber` property), and that if you have a bunch of `Claimant` objects, you don't have to remember whether you have normalized them or not.

---

You could also use a combination of the two methods: add a new property `NormalTaxNumber` which converts `TaxNumber` when needed, and which caches the result so that conversion doesn't have to be done again.

```
public class Claimant
{
    // ...

    private string m_normalTaxNumber;

    private string ConvertedTaxNumber
    {
        get { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(TaxNumber) ? "0" : TaxNumber; }
    }

    public string NormalTaxNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_normalTaxNumber == null)
            { m_normalTaxNumber = ConvertedTaxNumber; }
            return m_normalTaxNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

This only does the calculation once, keeps the original still available, and doesn't require to remember if you've called it before or not. If `TaxNumber` (the original value) isn't readonly, this is probably more trouble than it's worth as you will have to invalidate the cached value.

---

If you are never, never going to need to know whether the `TaxNumber` was originally null, empty or "0", the best advice (and the last strategy) is to convert to the form you want as soon as possible, preferably in the `Claimant` constructor, if the value of `TaxNumber` is known there.

If you are getting `Claimant` objects from a database, you could take this to its logical limit by doing the conversion on the database, either in a stored proc or in a view. If you are using LinqToSql to get the list of `Claimant` objects, a view could work for you but a stored proc might not.

---

I have assumed throughout that you want `TaxNumber` to be available as a string, and that by 0 you mean the string "0". If this isn't the case, and you actually want convert to an `int` (or similar), some of the strategies above will still work. You can `select` the converted value as an `int` in an anonymous type, you can make a new property `NormalTaxNumber` (with `int` type), whether cached or not cached, or you can do the conversion upon creation of a `Claimant` object. Obviously you can't overwrite the `string` `TaxNumber` with an `int`.

If you are parsing the `string` to an `int`, things like `NormalTaxNumber` with caching become more worthwhile, because the conversion from `string` to `int` is more costly. (Checking for `null` or `""` is actually very fast, however I thought it valuable to go through some different options anyway.)

Note that almost all of these should still be available to you if you can't modify the `Claimant` class. You can't write a new constructor, but you can write a factory method which encapsulates exactly the same behavior as a constructor. You can add `NormalizeTaxNumber` as an extension method, and while you can't add properties, you can add extension methods with no arguments which work almost exactly like properties.

My last observation is that `"0"` might not necessarily be a better value for missing data than `null` or `""`. Either of the latter is more commonly used to indicate missing values, especially `null`. Perhaps you should choose one of those as the default (and maybe apply one of the above strategies in reverse to enforce it as the only 'N/A' value?) If it's just a question of it looking nice when you print the object out, you could override `ToString()` to swap in the `"0"` only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
from c in CacheManager.ClaimantList.List
let taxNumber = c.TaxNumber == null || c.TaxNumber == "" ? "0" : c.TaxNumber
where ...
```

and then use the `taxNumber` variable rather than the column.